# Infragistics UltraGrid: GroupBy row ForeColor changes when clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Using Infragistics UltraGrid in WinForms in C#:

I am conditionally changing the color of the ForeColor of some GroupByRows on a grid.  When the user clicks the row, the color changes back to the active/selected/hot tracked/whatever color until they click on something else.  I'd like the text color of the rows that I have conditionally colored to never change.  Here's how I'm setting the color:

Row.Appearance.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;

Any idea how to make it stick even when the row is clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a draw filter to set the fore color of the description since this would apply at all times.

A simple example is the following draw filter which will make all group by rows that have an integer value that is even orange:

```
public class GroupByRowDrawFilter:IUIElementDrawFilter
{
    public bool DrawElement(DrawPhase drawPhase, ref UIElementDrawParams drawParams)
    {
        GroupByRowDescriptionUIElement element = (GroupByRowDescriptionUIElement)drawParams.Element;
        if (element.GroupByRow.Value is int)
        {
            int value = (int)element.GroupByRow.Value;
            if (value % 2 == 0)
            {
                drawParams.AppearanceData.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public DrawPhase GetPhasesToFilter(ref UIElementDrawParams drawParams)
    {
        if (drawParams.Element is GroupByRowDescriptionUIElement)
            return DrawPhase.BeforeDrawElement;
        return DrawPhase.None;
    }
}
```

To apply the draw filter use the following line of code:

```
this.ultraGrid1.DrawFilter = new GroupByRowDrawFilter();
```

Note that this approach requires that the condition be in the draw filter.  If this doesn't work for you, you could modify your logic where you are currently setting the ForeColor to set the Tag property of the GroupByRow instead and then check the Tag property in the draw filter to determine if you need to apply your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also change the

```
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectedRowAppearance.ForeColor = System.Drawning.Color.Orange;
```

or better

```
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.GroupByRowAppearance.ForeColor = System.Drawning.Color.Orange;
```

sorry, but I'm away from a PC where I can test.

Usually these properties could be changed effectively in the InitializeLayout event where you get the Layout object inside the event arguments.

```
e.Layout.Override.GroupByRowAppearance.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
```

EDIT: At the moment the only solution that I have found is the following

```
    private void grd_BeforeRowActivate(object sender, RowEventArgs e)
    {
        // You need to add the additional logic required by you to
        // determine which rows need to have the forecolo changed...
        if (e.Row.IsGroupByRow == true)
            grd.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveRowAppearance.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        else
            grd.DisplayLayout.Override.ResetActiveRowAppearance();
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I only want certain rows to be colored, so setting the property on the entire grid would not work.

Comment: Find a workaround, not very satisfying, but the forecolor change also when the row is Active

Comment: Hmm...still can't get it to work.  I've even tried just turning off active row appearances:
`
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveAppearancesEnabled = DefaultableBoolean.False;                grd.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectedAppearancesEnabled = DefaultableBoolean.False;
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveRowAppearance.ForeColor = Color.Orange;`

Comment: Well sometimes the countless property of this grid are overwhelming. I find useful to open the grid designer and select the button Modified Only. So I can better spot the settings modified and now hidden by other changes. Hope to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics says:

> the "Ability to have active and selected conditional appearances for the GroupByRows" has been determined to be a new product idea