# change row colors in a specific OutlookGroupBy group in UltraGrid in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, infragistics

I am using an ultragrid and inside i have values that i load into a datatable from a database. In my grid i group the rows into groups with OutlookGroupBy code. My rows in the grid are in two categories. The Priority 1 and 0. I want when the data are loaded the rows that are in priority 1 to get color red, and the others in priority 0 to be in normal color.

I use the ultragrid pro grammatically so i didnt use any of its features in the editor.

here is how i initialize my grid and how i load from database from another class:

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing

        Timer1.Enabled = True
        UltraGrid1.DataSource = Nothing
        Generic.openOrders(dt)
        UltraGrid1.DataSource = dt

        Dim band As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBand = UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0)
        UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.ViewStyleBand = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ViewStyleBand.OutlookGroupBy
        band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("PRIORITY"), True, True)
        band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("ORDERID"), False, True)
        band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("ORDERTIME"), False, True)
```

anyone has any idea of how can i change the row color into the priority 1 subrows??

Comment: Steve's approach below will work.  If you need the rows to be colored Red and not change when they are activated, then you may need to use a draw filter like what I provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142675/infragistics-ultragrid-groupby-row-forecolor-changes-when-clicked/11386417#11386417

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this approach:

First you need to subscribe the event `InitializeRow`, so add this by the designer or by code (eg. in Form_Load or before setting the DataSource of the grid)

```
grd.InitializeRow += new InitializeRowEventHandler(grd_InitializeRow);
```

then, in the event, write code like this

```
private void grd_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.Band.Index == 1)
    {
         if(Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells["PRIORITY"].Value) == 1)
              e.Row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that if you have set `CellAppearance` they will have precedence on `RowAppearance` and, if you have many rows it is better to initialize an `Appearance` object, store it in the `grid.DisplayLayout.Appearances` collection and reuse the same object for every row involved.

**Moreover, always with the aim of improving the performance,** to get the cell value it is better to use the `GetCellValue` method of the row. This will avoid  the creation of the a full Cell object just to retrieve its value. Things are a bit more complicated because you need an `UltraGridColumn` and not just the name of the column, but in the InitializeRow event, fired for each row, this is little price to pay.

```
private void grd_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.Band.Index == 1)
    {
         UltraGridColumn priorityColumn = e.Row.Band.Columns["PRIORITY"];
         if(Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.GetCellValue(priorityColumn)) == 1)
              e.Row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The same code in VB.NET

```
....
AddHandler grd.InitializeRow, AddressOf Me.grd_InitializeRow
....


Private Sub grd_InitializeRow(sender As System.Object, e As InitializeRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.Band.Index = 1 Then
        Dim priorityCol As UltraGridColumn = e.Row.Band.Columns("PRIORITY")
        If Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.GetCellValue(priorityCol)) = 1 Then
            e.Row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, the use the UltraGridColumn class, you need to add at the start of file

```
Imports Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid
```

Comment: I would recommend changing the line accessing the cells value to use e.Row.GetCellValue("PRIORITY") rather than accessing the value through the UltraGridCell object since the UltraGridCell objects are created as needed so this will use less memory.  http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WinGrid_Memory_Usage.html

Comment: thank you both for the replies guys. But one little problem. Can u write this for vb aswell?:P I keep getting errors on how to declare this 
grd.InitializeRow += new InitializeRowEventHandler(grd_InitializeRow);
and this UltraGridColumn priorityColumn = e.Row.Band.Columns["PRIORITY"];

Comment: thank you steve. I will fix my code tomorrow and post if i have any problem. Thanks for both of you again for the info

Comment: the code worked as a charm. I was missing the AddHandler. Thank you again people